# Wierd php file showed up on our FTP site

Tags: php

We have a third-party vendor who has an FTP site which allows us to upload files to our dedicated folder on their system. They contacted us about a php file that showed up that we didn't upload. I'm not familiar with php, but I'm worried there may have been a security compromise. It's a short script, but what is it doing?

```
<?php

@error_reporting(0);
@set_time_limit(0);
@ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

function read_file($filename)
{
    $file_data = '';
    if (@file_exists($filename))
    {
        $fp = @fopen($filename, 'r');
        if ($fp)
        {
            $file_data = @file_get_contents($filename);
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }

    return $file_data;
}

function detect_cms()
{
    $index_list = array(   
        'index.php',
        'index.php3',
        'index.htm',
        'index.html',
        'index.phtm',
        'index.phtml',
        'index.asp',
        'index.shtm',
        'index.shtml'
    );

    $cms_list = array(
        array('JFactory::', 'Joomla!'),
        array('drupal_bootstrap', 'Drupal'),
        array('wp-blog-header.php', 'Wordpress'),
        array('$modx', 'MODX'),
        array('typo3', 'TYPO3'),
        array('textpattern()', 'Textpattern'),
        array('IMAGECMS', 'ImageCMS')
    );

    foreach ($index_list as $index_file)
    {
        $index_data = read_file($index_file);
        if (strlen($index_file))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    foreach ($cms_list as $cms_item)
    {
        if (strpos($index_data, $cms_item[0]) !== false)
        {
            return $cms_item[1];
        }
    }

    return '';  
}

echo 'OK';
echo detect_cms().'|';

if (function_exists('php_uname'))
{
    echo @php_uname('s').'|'.
         @php_uname('r').'|'.
         @php_uname('v').'|'.
         @php_uname('m').'|';
} else
{
    echo '||||';
}

if (defined('PHP_INT_SIZE') && PHP_INT_SIZE == 8)
{
    echo '64|';
} else
{
    echo '32|';
}

if (function_exists('phpversion'))
{
    echo @phpversion().'|';
} else
{
    echo '|';
}

if (function_exists('get_loaded_extensions'))
{
    $extensions = @get_loaded_extensions();
    foreach ($extensions as $ext)
    {
        echo $ext.'|';
    }
}

?>
@error_reporting(0);
@set_time_limit(0);
@ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

function read_file($filename)
{
    $file_data = '';
    if (@file_exists($filename))
    {
        $fp = @fopen($filename, 'r');
        if ($fp)
        {
            $file_data = @file_get_contents($filename);
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }

    return $file_data;
}

function detect_cms()
{
    $index_list = array(   
        'index.php',
        'index.php3',
        'index.htm',
        'index.html',
        'index.phtm',
        'index.phtml',
        'index.asp',
        'index.shtm',
        'index.shtml'
    );

    $cms_list = array(
        array('JFactory::', 'Joomla!'),
        array('drupal_bootstrap', 'Drupal'),
        array('wp-blog-header.php', 'Wordpress'),
        array('$modx', 'MODX'),
        array('typo3', 'TYPO3'),
        array('textpattern()', 'Textpattern'),
        array('IMAGECMS', 'ImageCMS')
    );

    foreach ($index_list as $index_file)
    {
        $index_data = read_file($index_file);
        if (strlen($index_file))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    foreach ($cms_list as $cms_item)
    {
        if (strpos($index_data, $cms_item[0]) !== false)
        {
            return $cms_item[1];
        }
    }

    return '';  
}

echo 'OK';
echo detect_cms().'|';

if (function_exists('php_uname'))
{
    echo @php_uname('s').'|'.
         @php_uname('r').'|'.
         @php_uname('v').'|'.
         @php_uname('m').'|';
} else
{
    echo '||||';
}

if (defined('PHP_INT_SIZE') && PHP_INT_SIZE == 8)
{
    echo '64|';
} else
{
    echo '32|';
}

if (function_exists('phpversion'))
{
    echo @phpversion().'|';
} else
{
    echo '|';
}

if (function_exists('get_loaded_extensions'))
{
    $extensions = @get_loaded_extensions();
    foreach ($extensions as $ext)
    {
        echo $ext.'|';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: looks like a pre-attack script. someone is trying to identify a cms. Possibly to provide a more narrow attack with known security holes instead of something that tries all cases for all cms packages.

Comment: This is a probing script. It gives them an idea of what they're capable of doing on that server. The next step would be to upload a new file that can be used to infect the system, or even worse, to lay dormant as a UDP attacker in a botnet. The reason for this script is to avoid causing errors to show up, and the like. This helps keep their footprint minimal and makes it harder to trace later on. Resolving this is easy: Change the password, 14+ characters, 2 special characters, alpha numeric, mix of lower/uppercase.

Comment: Also, contact the 3rd party (vendor) with the upload script, which is most likely the culprit. 9 times out of 10, that's what it is, a badly constructed uploading mechanism with security holes.

Comment: FTP... drop that. SFTP perhaps, but FTP = clear text authorization info for the world to see.

Comment: I may have said FTP when its really SFTP, I'll double check with our vendor on that. Thanks for the help, friends!